# Python cant find module adbutils

Tags: python, package

I was using the adbutils package without any trouble. I restarted my pc and it doesn't work anymore. I get the error "No module named 'adbutils'". Which is very weird because it worked earlier and I am sure it is installed, I can straight up see the folder in my directory. Pip uninstalling and installing didn't work as well. I did get a lot of requirement not statisfied errors when reinstalling it. Other packages that are installed in the same directory do work without a problem. If anyone know why this is please let me know. Thank you

```
File "c:/Users/marti_wfv2bf9/Desktop/Python Projects/ADB testing/adb-testing.py", line 2, in <module>
import adbutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adbutils'
PS C:\Users\marti_wfv2bf9\Desktop\Python Projects\ADB testing>
```

This is what I get when I try to reinstall it with pip3

```
pip3 install adbutils
Collecting adbutils
  Using cached adbutils-0.8.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: apkutils2<2.0,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from adbutils) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: whichcraft in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from adbutils) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from adbutils) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from adbutils) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: deprecation<3.0,>=2.0.6 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from adbutils) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: retry>=0.9 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from adbutils) (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyelftools in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from apkutils2<2.0,>=1.0.0->adbutils) (0.26)
Requirement already satisfied: cigam in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from apkutils2<2.0,>=1.0.0->adbutils) (0.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from apkutils2<2.0,>=1.0.0->adbutils) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests->adbutils) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests->adbutils) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests->adbutils) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from requests->adbutils) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from deprecation<3.0,>=2.0.6->adbutils) (20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.4.2 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from retry>=0.9->adbutils) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: py<2.0.0,>=1.4.26 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from retry>=0.9->adbutils) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\marti_wfv2bf9\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from packaging->deprecation<3.0,>=2.0.6->adbutils) (2.4.7)
Installing collected packages: adbutils
Successfully installed adbutils-0.8.1
```

Comment: Could it be that you used a different python editor earlier?

Comment: no, used the same editor

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: added the errors in the post

Comment: What version of python is it?

Comment: Python is 3.8.3